# Software for maintaining a pattern catalog

Tags: knowledge-base

Analysis patterns and design patterns are powerful concepts for building knowledge bases. I'm looking for a software to easily collect and maintain pattern catalogues / pattern languages.

Solutions that come to mind, however, do not cover my requirements entirely:

- concept / mind mapping software
- wiki (together with site templates)
- ontology editors
- UML editors
- ticket systems

What I have in mind, has to parts:

I. a graph editor to describe how patterns (respresentes as nodes) relate

- with different graphical types of nodes and edges

II. a simple form that can be filled out for each pattern

- while the form definition should depend on the pattern type and must be adjustable
- supporting attachment of images, URLs, files and
- full text search

If one of the systems mentioned above (maybe via plugin) still meets my needs, I'd also be thankful for a suggestion. There is no need for multi-user support.

Target environment:

- web (not necessarily self-hostable) or
- Windows desktop